# Microsoft Graph -> Use the singleValueExtendedProperty in OData $select when expanded $expand

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm able to fetch events from the users calendar with a [Single Value Extended Property](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty_get) in it by using the correct `$expand` parameter.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/calendarview?startDateTime=2018-10-09&endDateTime=2019-01-09&$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String {cfe1492e-2c52-462d-8f0d-c1139326d46f} Name PropertyName')`

This outputs the first 10 events with some that have this property filled (YEAY!!).

But how do I use the `$select` parameter in combination with this?

Because the above query would return all properties for those events while I'm only interested in the `id`, `subject` and `singleValueProperties` properties for all events. According to [this page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters) I should be able to only select the properties my application wants with the `$select` parameter but I have no clue how to use it with the `singleValueProperty` (or any other expanded properties).

I've tried the following list (in combination with the $expand to actually get the property included):

```
$select=id,subject,singleValueProperties (single value properties not included)
$select=id,subject,singleValueProperties.value (not included)
$select=id,subject,singleValueProperties/value (bad request)
$select=id,subject,singleValueProperties.* (not included)
$select=id,subject (not included)
```

Comment: What do you get for results when simply append `&$select=id,subject` to your call?

Comment: That part works perfect (in following the specs), then I only get the id and subject. The singleValueProperties are then not given back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be a [Known Issue](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/known_issues) with Microsoft Graph. Under [Query Parameters](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/known_issues#query-parameter-limitations):

> - `$expand`:
>
>   - No support for `nextLink`
>   - No support for more than 1 level of expand
>   - **No support with extra parameters (`$filter`, `$select`)**

The wording here is a little odd, since `$expand` and `$select` certainly work together in other places. That said, I've been able to reproduce the same behavior and there *clearly* cases like this where `$expand` and `$select` do not.

This is also documented in [Use query parmeters](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#expand-parameter):

> **Note:** Not all relationships and resources support the `$expand` query parameter. For example, you can expand the `directReports`, `manager`, and `memberOf` relationships on a `user`, but you cannot expand its `events`, `messages`, or `photo` relationships. **Not all resources or relationships support using `$select` on expanded items.**

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Maybe this could be better explained in the docs.