# Expanded SingleValueExtendedProperties do not show up when combined with $select

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, odata, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm currently using Microsoft Graph to retrieve appointments from a users calendar. I need to access the singleValueExtendedProperties and only a few properties of the appointment.

Accessing this url

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/XXXXXX/calendarView?startDateTime=2023-05-01T12:00:00&endDateTime=2023-05-30T12:00:00&$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String {GUID1} Name Creator' or id eq 'String {GUID2} Name Type')&$top=50`

returns the entire appointments with it's singleValueExtendeProperties.

However, when I combine that with a select like so

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/XXXXXX/calendarView?startDateTime=2023-05-01T12:00:00&endDateTime=2023-05-30T12:00:00&$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String {GUID1} Name Creator' or id eq 'String {GUID2} Name Type')&$select=id,start,end,isAllDay,showAs,categories,subject,sensitivity,singleValueExtendedProperties&$top=50`

I only get the selected fields without the singleValueExtendedProperties.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue/bug with the Graph [Microsoft Graph -> Use the singleValueExtendedProperty in OData $select when expanded $expand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52723890/microsoft-graph-use-the-singlevalueextendedproperty-in-odata-select-when-exp) one way of working around it is to include the extendedproperty you want returned in a filter clause, even though you may not want to filter items you can make your filter generic so it just returns all item with that property eg this is an example just using the extended property for subject (note your shouldn't have

```html
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/calendarView?startDateTime=2022-09-01T19:00:00Z&endDateTime=2022-09-10T19:00:00Z&$select=Subject,Start,End,singleValueExtendedProperties&$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String 0x0037')&$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep: ep/id eq 'String 0x0037' and ep/value ne null)
```

IMO Microsoft should just fix this on the backend.